# Where does info file exist

Tags: info

I want to find the location of **info** file of the [jcal](http://www.nongnu.org/jcal/) program.
It has appropriate info when I call `info jcal`. The output of `info -w jcal` is:

```
*manpages*
```

- Did I do wrong way to get the full location of **info** file? What is the
- best way to get the **info** file location?

*Dist: Slackware Current.

jcal: 0.4.1

info: 4.13*

Comment: Please state distribution and version number in question.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Added to the question. Thank you.

Comment: I meant distribution version.

Comment: I've put distribution version: Slackware Current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `info` looks for files at places defined in `$INFOPATH` variable (usually `/usr/share/info/`, etc), but if it doesn't find the appropriate file there, as a fallback it switches to the `man` pages for help (see `$MANPATH` variable) and prints exactly the same content as `man`. So if `info -w` shows **manpages** then try `man -w` to get the information you wanted.